# How to upload a jar file for batch processing?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a Java process which is an executable jar file. This java process reads in a file, performs some processing and then writes the output to a new file. I'd like to share this process via a cloud service but I'm what to use.

Is there a Heroku or Amazon setup I could use for this ?

Using Amazon I could upload the file to processed Amazon Simple Storage Service and trigger the process job and then expose the results of this job via a web service?

I'm just enquiring about high level options as I'm not sure where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

Where do these input files come from? What services consume them afterwards?

One possible workflow on AWS.
1. Modify your jar to be able read from S3 and write to S3
2. Create a webservice in this jar with a simple API that takes an S3 location and gives back an S3 location where the output will go.
3. Run this jar on an EC2 host, possibly using Elastic Beanstalk

The workflow would be something like:
1. Upload an input file to s3
2. Call the webservice, providing the S3 url to the input file
3. The webservice does the job and writes the file to another S3 bucket, giving back the URL

This can be modified in all sorts of ways, but it's difficult to give more guidance without knowing more of your requirements.